# Python Web Scraping with search and non dynamic URI

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm a begginer in the world of python and web-scrapers, i am used to make scrapers with dynamic URLs, where the URI change when i input specific parameters in the URL itself.
Ex:  Wikipedia.
(if i input a search named "Stack Overflow" i will have a URI that looks like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow)

At the moment i was challenged to develop a web-scraper to collect data from [this page](http://comprasnet.gov.br/acesso.asp?url=/ConsultaLicitacoes/ConsLicitacao_texto.asp).

The field **"Texto/Termos a serem pesquisados"** corresponds a search field, but when i input the search the URL stays the same not letting me to get the right HTML code for my research.

I am used to work with BeautifulSoup and Requests to do the scraping thing, but in this case it has no use, since the URL stays the same after the search.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://comprasnet.gov.br/acesso.asp?url=/ConsultaLicitacoes/ConsLicitacao_texto.asp'
html = requests.get(url)
bs0bj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'html.parser')

print(bsObj)
# And from now on i cant go any further
```

Usually i would do something like

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'
input = input('Input your search :)
search = url + input
```

And then do all the BeautifulSoup thing, and findAll thing to get my data from the HTML code.

I have tried to use Selenium too, but im looking for something different than that due to all the webdriver thing. With the following piece of code i have achieved to some odd results but i still cant scrape the HTML in a good way.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Acess the page and input the search on the field

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://comprasnet.gov.br/acesso.asp?url=/ConsultaLicitacoes/ConsLicitacao_texto.asp')
driver.switch_to.frame('main2')
busca = driver.find_element_by_id("txtTermo")
busca.send_keys("GESTAO DE PESSOAS")
#data_inicio = driver.find_element_by_id('dt_publ_ini')
#data_inicio.send_keys("01/01/2018")
#data_fim = driver.find_element_by_id('dt_publ_fim')
#data_fim.send_keys('20/12/2018')
botao = driver.find_element_by_id('ok')
botao.click()
```

So given all that:

- There is a way to scrape data from these static urls ?
- Can i input a search in the field via code ?
- Why cant i scrape the right source code ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your initial search page is using frames for the searching & results, which makes it harder for `BeautifulSoup` to work with it. I was able to obtain the search results by using a slightly different URL and [`MechanicalSoup`](https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup) instead:

```
>>> from mechanicalsoup import StatefulBrowser
>>> sb = StatefulBrowser()
>>> sb.open('http://comprasnet.gov.br/ConsultaLicitacoes/ConsLicitacao_texto.asp')
<Response [200]>
>>> sb.select_form()  # select the search form
<mechanicalsoup.form.Form object at 0x7f2c10b1bc18>
>>> sb['txtTermo'] = 'search text'  # input the text to search for
>>> sb.submit_selected()  # submit the form
<Response [200]>
>>> page = sb.get_current_page()  # get the returned page in BeautifulSoup form
>>> type(page)
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
```

Note that the URL I'm using here is that of the frame that has the search form and not the page you provided that was inlining it. This removes one layer of indirection.

`MechanicalSoup` is built on top of `BeautifulSoup` and provides some tools for interacting with websites in a similar way to the old `mechanize` library.